# How do programs that can find dictionary words within anagrams work?

Tags: database, dictionary, combinations, permutation

Examples include http://www.thewordfinder.com/, http://www.anagram-solver.org/, or the various applications for "cheating" at anagram based games such as Words With Friends.

Where would one begin if they were looking to create an application with similar functionality using Swift?

Since this seems to be getting down-voted, can someone tell me where the best place to ask this question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a word list into a prefix tree (especially one that uses extra memory to avoid sparse arrays) should allow one to efficiently check all permutations of an input word, since entire branches of the search can be eliminated quickly.

Let's consider a simplified example. Assume our dictionary contains 3 words: `aab`, `abb`, and `abc`. If we convert it to a prefix tree, that would look like:

```
a
    ab
    b
        b
        c
```

Where indentation indicates children of the row above. All the words in our dictionary start with an `a`, followed by either `ab` or `b`, and in the latter case followed by either `b` or `c`. As you can see, we don't branch on every letter, but rather on alternatives. This helps keep the size of the tree down.

Now, if we iterate over all permutations of our input word `cba`:

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

All permutations that start with a letter other than `a` can be eliminated quickly since our prefix tree has no matching entry at the root level. `acb` can be eliminated on the second check, meaning only `abc` would find a match. If you integrate the check into your algorithm for generating permutations, you could match incrementally and avoid generating partial permutations that don't match the current branch of the tree you're exploring.

The comment about avoiding sparse trees is to avoid having to use binary search to match children of the current branch. Rather, an array of 26 elements, indexed by the ascii values of the letters (pick upper or lowercase and be consistent), should allow very quick lookups, at the cost of additional memory.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Could you explain the layout of the letters in the prefix tree a little more?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie for a much more detailed explanation.